# Changing the state of one component that gets declared multiple times in React - Better Practices?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-component, array.prototype.map, react-state

Firt off, this code works for me but I was wondering if anything looks off.

I tried experimenting with changing the state of one component that gets called multiple times and it was more difficult then I realized in React. I was able to get it done but I feel like I was doing some bad practice in the toggleClass. If it's good practice but there's a better way to do this or if nothing is wrong, this noob would love to know.

**ButtonContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from './Button'

export default class ButtonContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
        colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
        active: true
    }
    toggleClass = (color, id) => {
        let colors = [...this.state.colors]
        colors.map((newColor, index) => {
            if (id === index) {
                let copy = { ...colors[index] }
                if (color === 'not') {
                    if (index === 0) {
                        copy = 'red'
                    } else if (index === 1) {
                        copy = 'blue'
                    } else if (index === 2) {
                        copy = 'green'
                    }
                } else {
                    copy = 'not'
                }
                colors[index] = copy
                this.setState({ colors })
            }
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='button-container'>
                {this.state.colors.map((color, index) =>
                    <Button
                        toggleClass={this.toggleClass}
                        key={index}
                        id={index}
                        name={color}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Button.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Button = (props) => (
    <button
        className={`button-component ${props.name}`}
        onClick={() => props.toggleClass(props.name, props.id)}
    >
        {props.name}
    </button>
)

export default Button
```

**CSS**

```
.button-container {
    margin: 10rem auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.button-component {
    padding: 4rem;
    margin: 0 2rem;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}

.not {
    background: none;
}
```

---

-- **UPDATE** --

Improved toggleClass

```
toggleClass = (color, id) => {
        let colors = [...this.state.colors]
        const newColors = colors.map((newColor, index) => {
            if (id === index) {
                const copyMap = { 0: 'red', 1: 'blue', 2: 'green' }
                const copy = color === 'not' ? copyMap[index] : 'not'
                return copy
            } else {
                return newColor
            }
        })
        this.setState({ colors: newColors })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good on you for seeking advice - learning how to do things the right way early on will pay dividends.

- The purpose of `Array.map` is to create a new array based on one you already have. Best practice is to avoid doing extra things in there like setState. But you should *never* under any circumstances change the contents of an array while you are iterating over it (`colors[index] = copy`)
- There are a couple of unused variables floating around, `this.state.active` and `newColor`. Clean this up and the code will be easier to read.
- Most of the time you should avoid using `let` declarations and use `const` instead. Over time you'll find that code which transforms variables is much harder to reason about than code which creates new variables with descriptive names.
- One pattern that might help clean up those long if statements is to build a reference object (or array).

```
const copyMap = { 0: 'red', 1: 'blue', 'green' }
const copy = color === 'not' ? copyMap[index] : 'not'
```

Could replace all of this code:

```
                if (color === 'not') {
                    if (index === 0) {
                        copy = 'red'
                    } else if (index === 1) {
                        copy = 'blue'
                    } else if (index === 2) {
                        copy = 'green'
                    }
                } else {
                    copy = 'not'
                }
```

Comment: As a side note you can install a linter like `eslint`, which will read your code and attempt to find opportunities for improvement.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try to setState and change the contents of the array outside of the map.

Comment: I improved the toggleClass. Definitely looks and feels better.

Comment: awesome! congrats :)